Curve a procedural pattern around a mask
I'm trying to wrap a proceduraly generated pattern around a hand painted mask that I've drawn. The issue is that I can't figure out how to wrap the procedural pattern to curve around my mask so that it gives off a nice transition following the path of the outline/mask. For instance, If I start on a new mask, paint 1 single white dot on a black canvas, then I'd like the pattern to be outlining the circle, then continue on as I keep drawing following the outline.

